# ¿como puedo corregir este error en un formulario java con conxion a Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo 4 formularios clientes proveedores productos ventas en java en el formulario ventas que conecta a BD de Mysql * uso queryBrow

me salta un cartel y en laBD lo tengo con Auto increment a Id cliente y tiene FK en ventas pero en el Formulario cuando acuerda Ventas sin insertar por teclado el Id. y que se agregue la venta.

mi codigo es:

```
try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");// coneccion a la base de datos
        coneccion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cursoj2ee","root","admin");
        // establecer conexion ala base de datos
        instruccion = coneccion.createStatement();// consultar a la base de datos
        // consultar a la base de datos
       instruccion.executeUpdate("insert into ventas (Fecha,Descripcion,Cantidad,Precio) values('"+jTextField9.getText()+"','"+jTextField10.getText()+"','"+jTextField11.getText()+"','"+jTextField12.getText()+"')");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se ha guardado un nueva venta");
    }
    catch(SQLException exeptionsql){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,exeptionsql.getMessage(),
            "error al insertar datos",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
    catch( ClassNotFoundException clasenoencontrada){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,clasenoencontrada.getMessage(),
            "no se encontro el controlador ",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);

    }
    finally {
        try {
            coneccion.close();
            instruccion.close();
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"cerro correctamente la base de datos");
        }

        // handle exceptions closing statement and connection
        catch ( SQLException sqlException ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,
                sqlException.getMessage(), " no cerro correctamente la base de datos",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );

            System.exit( 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN6xc.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi sql en el queryb

mi tabla ventas

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cursoj2ee`.`ventas`;
CREATE TABLE  `cursoj2ee`.`ventas` (
  `ID_Ventas` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_Cliente` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ID_Producto` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ID_Provee` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Descripcion` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cantidad` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Precio` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Ventas`),
  KEY `FK_ventas_3` (`ID_Cliente`),
  KEY `FK_ventas_2` (`ID_Provee`),
  KEY `FK_ventas_4` (`ID_Producto`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ventas_4` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Producto`) REFERENCES `productos` (`ID_Producto`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ventas_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Cliente`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`ID_Cliente`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ventas_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Provee`) REFERENCES `proveedores` (`ID_Provee`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2023 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Te recomendaría que te dieras una pasada en (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4774/c%c3%b3mo-escribo-un-buen-t%c3%adtulo?cb=1), ya que tu pregunta puede ser cerrada.

Comment: gracias, creo que ya quedo mejor?

Comment: Sí, déjame ver si entendí: Lo que quieres es que tu usuario no ingrese un ID ya que este es autoincrement?

Comment: hola tristan si . por ejemplo los inserto y no hay  problema guarda los id pero yo quiero que sean solo los datos que se guarden al darle agregar venta. y que los id se generen solos ya que son auto increment ypuse que sean null pero no me dejo tampoco.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la tabla `ventas`, en ella se define un campo `ID_Cliente` que esta definido como NOT NULL, no hay datos en el INSERT para este campo.

Debes incluir datos para este campo en el INSERT o si el valor puede estar vacío en un principio, cambialo a NULL.

ALTER TABLE ventas MODIFY COLUMN `ID_Producto` int(10) unsigned NULL

De la misma manera para otros campos que no estan incluidos en el insert y son NOT NULL, como `ID_Producto` y `ID_Provee`

Comment: claro pero lo que debo hacer es que el usuario no ingrese el Id por teclado , si no que sea Auto incrementable. osea me tengo que fjar en el codigo de java en el INSERT?

Comment: en alguna parte de la aplicacion se debe crear el cliente, proveedor y luego dicha informacion se debera usar de referencia para tu insert

Comment: bueno gracias voy a revisar aunque no te comprendi bien, souy nueva en esto y me cuesta un poco manejar los errores.

Comment: Falta mas informacion en el fragmento de codigo que tienes, es probable que falten algunos pasos para llegar a este punto. Producto, cliente, proveedor son valores que deben crearse o seleccionarse previamente. Revisa la especificacion que te dieron y aporta mas informacion de lo que lleves hecho.

Comment: instruccion.executeUpdate("insert into ventas(id_Ventas,id_Cliente,id_Producto,id_provee,Fecha,Descripcion,Cantidad,Precio) values('"+jTextField5.getText()+"','"+jTextField6.getText()+"','"+jTextField7.getText()+"','"+jTextField8.getText()+"','"+jTextField9.getText()+"','"+jTextField10.getText()+"','"+jTextField11.getText()+"','"+jTextField12.getText()+"')");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se ha guardado un nueva venta");

Comment: ahora lo tengo asi y me inserta los ID pero no quiero hacer eso ,lo que necesito es que se guarden datos pero no Los id ya que son Auto incrementables en mi BD....y el usuario no debe insertar por teclado Los Id

Comment: Solo ID_Ventas es auto increment, asi que no necesitas agregarlo. Para los valores de cliente, producto, proveedor los valores deberian provenir de algun campo de seleccion (Dropdown) que permita elegir uno pero no escribirlo directamente por el usuario